# angularjs Hide objects with certain class when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've looked up the ng-show directive but none of the examples seemed to fit my case.

I have a certain amount of divs with the class 'foo' which is dynamically generated based on some logic. I want to hide all the divs with that class when a checkbox is selected.

**edit:**

I solved it with this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="hideClosed" checked>

<div ng-show="{{location.isOpen}}" ng-hide="hideClosed && {{!location.isOpen}}"></div>
```

Only problem now is that the checkbox does not start initially checked. I tried adding ng-checked="true" to the checkbox, but it didn't hide the closed ones until it was un-checked and checked again.

Comment: Why not give each of divs the `ng-show` attribute when it is dynamically generated?

Comment: You could try using `ng-checked` on the `<input>`  so that it's checked whenever hideClosed is true (or false) to set up the initial checkbox state.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I just had to set the value of hideClosed to true in the controller.

Comment: Glad to be of help - I went ahead and posted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try giving each of the divs the `ng-show` attribute when they are dynamically generated.  This will make them automatically hide or show depending on the model.

Then you can use the `ng-checked` attribute on the checkbox to bind the "checked" state of checkbox to the value in the model that shows and hides the elements.